# @Autowired variables access in Spock setupSpec()

Tags: java, spring, spock, spring-test

I need to execute block of code once upon startup on the `Spock` tests. I cannot use `@Autowired` in `setupSpec()` which is default method for such initialisation, however `@Bean`s would not be loaded till that time.

Found on web (dating back to 2015) [source](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/267) :

> The behavior is a consequence of the design of Spring's TestContext framework. I don't
> see a way to change it without hitting other problems. The situation isn't any different
> when using the TestContext framework with JUnit.

It's been 6 years already, is there any clean way to do this? I want to omit dirty workarounds

Answer (score 6):

You are in luck, thanks to @erdi for implementing this in [Add support for injection into @Shared fields in spock-spring module](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/pull/1255), you can try the feature in the Spock Snapshot 2.0 builds, and it will be in the Spock-2.0M5 release. You need to opt-in into `@Shared` injection via placing `@EnableSharedInjection` on your specification, also really important, that you read the javadoc and understand the mentioned implications of doing that.